# how to focus on form in Windows-CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i have this method:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '1')
            {
```

how to take focus on Form1 after i insert any text on TextBox

thank's in advance

Comment: The form should not get the focus.  Post some more code, what is this event handler really doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `Focus` method on the Form, i.e.

```
this.Focus()
```